# Order list of objects

Tags: python, django

I have the list of objects and I want to order by date. Here it is how I am trying to do it:

```
list_name.order_by('date')
```

Here it is the model of these objects:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

The list consist of spesific filtered objects. However, I get error: `'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'`. So, what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: are you asking how to sort a list in python?

Comment: You need to apply `order_by` on the `QuerySet` itself not list.

Comment: Yes, how to sort a Python list by data?

Comment: Try this: list_name = Tweet.objects.order_by('date')

Comment: For sorting a list of dictionary, you can use 'sorted' functionality in python   newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['date'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic way to sort a list (or anything that's `iterable`) in Python is to use the function `sorted(iterable, key=key_function)`.  The key argument is a function that returns the comparison value for each item to be sorted.

To apply this generic solution to your case you might use something like `sorted(list_name, key=lambda tweet: tweet.date)`.

***However***, because you don't have a generic list but rather a list of items from the database provided by Django, which is order-aware, you should solve your problem in the chain of function calls you use to retrieve the objects in the first place.